# Unable to sort array of items with dynamic key

Tags: javascript, angular

I have implemented custom pipe to sort records as below

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({
      name: 'sortpipe'
    })
    export class SortPipe implements PipeTransform {

      transform(data: any, args?: string): any {
        if (!data) { return; }
        let sortedData = data.sort((item: any, item1: any) => (item.args> item1.args) ? 1 : ((item1.args> item.args) ? -1 : 0));
        return sortedData;
      }

    }
```

I have applied it as below in html page

```
<ejs-multiselect id='multiselect-checkbox' #checkbox='ngModel' [dataSource]="dropDownList.severity | sortpipe:[dropDownList.severity, 'Value']"........
```

below is my sample data from API

```
[{Key: "8baa71ae-3c14-11e9-8be6-90b11c61d394", Value: "Doors"}
{Key: "e10a4802-3f36-11e9-8d5a-90b11c61d394", Value: "Walls"}
{Key: "194f69a0-39c8-11e9-8be6-90b11c61d394", Value: "Windows"}
{Key: "d0c75562-5c31-11e9-9de4-90b11c61d394", Value: "Ducts"}
{Key: "556fba82-6102-11e9-b459-90b11c61d394", Value: "Air Terminals"}
{Key: "3cbc77b0-62af-11e9-b99a-90b11c61d394", Value: "Areas"}
{Key: "4a0c0156-62af-11e9-b99a-90b11c61d394", Value: "Cable Tray Fittings"}
{Key: "8aff8a34-62af-11e9-b99a-90b11c61d394", Value: "Cable Trays"}
{Key: "4a2afb1e-62b0-11e9-b99a-90b11c61d394", Value: "Casework"}]
```

Based on the Value property i would like to sort the records. so i am sending Value as parameter to transform(--) method.
But the records are not sorting.

Please let me know if you have any solution.

Comment: `item.args` looks for the property "args" of item. You want `item[args]` instead. In this way, if `args` is actually `'Value'`, it will evaluate to `item['Value']` which is equivalent to `item.Value`, which is the desired check.

Comment: Also, I think you should call the pipe like this `[dataSource]="dropDownList.severity | sortpipe: 'Value'".`

Comment: sorry not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [briosheje](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56807158/1160794) mentionned, you need to use `item[args]` instead of `item.args`.

Also, when calling the pipe, you only need to pass 'Value' as an argument, not an array containing the source and 'Value'.

```
<ejs-multiselect id='multiselect-checkbox' 
#checkbox='ngModel' 
[dataSource]="dropDownList.severity | sortpipe:'Value'"
```

Here is a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c4umma)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the filter actually works (joins the function and passes the correct parameters), you're just accessing the object's property in the wrong way.

Use the bracket notation to evaluate the property correctly, otherwise you will access the literal `args` property of the looped items.

```
let sortedData = data.sort((item: any, item1: any) => (item[args]> item1[args]) ? 1 : ((item1[args]> item[args]) ? -1 : 0));
```

In a nutshell:

`item[args]` will evaluate to `item['Value']` if `args` is `Value`.

`item.args`, instead, **always** evaluates to `item['args']`, which is always `undefined` in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String#prototype#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to sort the strings according to their sort-order.

```js
const data = [{Key: "8baa71ae-3c14-11e9-8be6-90b11c61d394", Value: "Doors"},
{Key: "e10a4802-3f36-11e9-8d5a-90b11c61d394", Value: "Walls"},
{Key: "194f69a0-39c8-11e9-8be6-90b11c61d394", Value: "Windows"},
{Key: "d0c75562-5c31-11e9-9de4-90b11c61d394", Value: "Ducts"},
{Key: "556fba82-6102-11e9-b459-90b11c61d394", Value: "Air Terminals"},
{Key: "3cbc77b0-62af-11e9-b99a-90b11c61d394", Value: "Areas"},
{Key: "4a0c0156-62af-11e9-b99a-90b11c61d394", Value: "Cable Tray Fittings"},
{Key: "8aff8a34-62af-11e9-b99a-90b11c61d394", Value: "Cable Trays"},
{Key: "4a2afb1e-62b0-11e9-b99a-90b11c61d394", Value: "Casework"}];

const res = data.sort((a, b) => a.Value.localeCompare(b.Value));
console.log(res);
```

Modify your pipe to:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'sortpipe'
})
export class SortPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(data: any, args?: string): any {
    if (!data) { return; }
    let sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => a.Value.localeCompare(b.Value));
    return sortedData;
  }
}
```